# How to get 0 instead of 'NaN' in SELECT COUNT(*) request?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to count quantity of some condition and avoid 'NaN' in result.
I tried ways with CASE and COALESCE constructions but have no needed result:

```
-- 1st: it works with 'NaN' in part of results:
SELECT response_date, 
    COUNT(*) AS views_per_day
FROM tab
WHERE v_result = condition
GROUP BY response_date
ORDER BY response_date

-- 2nd: it works with no effect, exact like first code:
SELECT response_date, 
    COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS views_per_day
FROM tab
WHERE v_result = condition
GROUP BY response_date
ORDER BY response_date

-- 3rd: it doesn't work:
SELECT response_date, 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 'NaN' THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(*)
    END AS views_per_day
FROM tab
WHERE v_result = condition
GROUP BY response_date
ORDER BY response_date
```

UPDATE
[image]

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected result for this data

Comment: Expected result - 0 instead of "NaN'.

Comment: There must be something else going on. I fail to see how `COUNT(*)` can possibly return `NaN` in the first place.

Comment: You should provide both sample input data AND the expected result. You only added one of them, so we can't see what is your issue. It's also recommended to provide such data as text rather than as image because this allows people to copy the text and try out possible solutions

Comment: This should be impossible. Perhaps it is your client's doing. Try again with a trustworthy client like `psql` and see if you see the same result. Test data to reproduce the result would be helpful.

Comment: Really it could be! I don't have direct acsess to DB and do it wia Python script. But anyway, how to get exact 0 in that kind of request, nothing else?

Comment: consruction     
CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) = NULL THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(*)
    END
works without any effect as well((
I think the problem is in empty cell. How to set it in exact 0, not empty?

Comment: So, you don't even have a PostgreSQL client to test? Are you positively sure that your Python script is completely right?

Comment: It looks like the client is doing some floating point math on the results; `count` never returns null or NaN, it wouldn't make any sense. Assuming you're showing an example of _actual query you're sending_ - which seems unlikely, since the queries you are showing wouldn't show the row in the first place, for obvious reasons. Most likely, there's an expansion going on to give results for every day even if there is no data for that day, and that's where the null (which probably gets translated to NaN in the script) comes from. Look there.

Comment: To ALL! THANKS A LOT. The request was a part of much bigger one. And the trouble was arising at JOIN stage. So, the qustion is incorrect and I will delete it very soon. Your answers and comments were very helpful and I was not able to find out the reason without you. I just say THANK YOU and sorry for my mistake.

Comment: A can't delete this incorrect qustion (((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was not in the request. This request is a part of much bigger SQL-request. And I thought the problem goes from SQL response. In fact, the problem was in handling in Python's script - I had no direct acsess to DB and did it through script. At one of stages of SQL request I did a join of tables - and the data's gap arised there. Already Python's script interprets NULL of SQL as 'NaN' and display it.
It turned out that the solution is very simple:

```
SELECT COALESCE(views_per_day, 0) AS views_per_day
```

Thanks to all who helped me to clarify the details.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use Subquery**

SELECT response_date,
COUNT(*) AS views_per_day

FROM tab
WHERE v_result in (SELECT v_result FROM tab is not null)

GROUP BY response_date

ORDER BY response_date

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In MsSQL we can use **ISNULL()**:

```
SELECT response_date, ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS views_per_day
FROM tab
WHERE v_result = condition
GROUP BY response_date
ORDER BY response_date
```